# When to use if (document.all&&document.getElementById) condition

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

Would like to know when to use, This applies for what browser ?

```
if (document.all&&document.getElementById) {
// Some code block
}
```

Comment: Never use this. It is an ages old method to detect one of the IE versions, 6 I think. What do you want to do?

Comment: I found that approach here http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns/ To implement li:hover on IE 6,7 since they don't support it. I think it is better if (document.getElementById) { // Some code } makes sense to in the context i have mentioned. Thanks all, +1 for Crowder for Feature Deteection tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's any significant browser left that doesn't support `document.getElementById`. Even IE6 supports it (although it gets it wrong — [details](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html) — but it does the same thing with `document.all`). I'd just use `document.getElementById` rather than `document.all`.

If you're using this just to detect the browser, rather than specifically because you want to use `document.all` or `document.getElementById`, *browser* detection is generally a bad idea. Instead, look at doing *feature* detection, testing for the actual features you want. There are some great examples of feature detection [here](http://kangax.github.com/cft/) and [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html).

---

**Off-topic**: If you're looking to do any significant cross-browser work, you might consider using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They'll smooth over browser differences for you, provide some very useful utility functions, and even (in some cases) fix browser bugs like IE's broken handling of `document.getElementById` (jQuery does that, for instance, some others may as well).

Answer (score 0):

`document.all` was a feature implemented by old versions of IE (IE3 and higher). It was also implemented by Opera, in an attempt to be compatible with IE-only sites.

However `document.all` is no longer recommended for use in any situation -- it is entirely obsolete. IE and Opera have kept support for it because there may be some old code that still uses it, but there is no place for it in modern code.

There are some script libraries which implement a version of `document.all` in Javascript, to allow old code to be run on modern browsers. For this reason, it isn't even worth using `document.all` as a browser test (as you've shown it in the question). In fact, all I have to do to break your test is write `document.all = true;`.

`document.getElememtById` was first implemented by IE in v5.0, so the condition you've given in the question would have been written in the days of IE5, and would have been a primitive browser-detection code for IE5.0 and higher, since that was (at the time) the only browser that supported both methods. But as already discussed, it is pretty much useless now, and is more likely to cause you problems than make anything work.

Comment: afaik IE3 doesn't support `document.all`

Comment: @Knu - it's been a *very* long time since I used IE4, let alone IE3, but I was under the impression that IE3 was when JScript was introduced, and that `document.all` was one of the original features (after all, it's a neccessity for the script to have at least some kind of access to the DOM). But I'm happy to be wrong about that. Either way, the point holds that it is obsolete and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 0):

> This applies for what browser ?

`if (document.all)` targets IE4+, Opera between v5 (v4 on linux) and [v9.5](http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/2008/01/25/document-all-true), Konqueror 2, iCab 2 and 3, Omniweb 4 (before v4.5) and some obscure browsers using the Rhino javascript engine.
`if (document.getElementById)` targets any DOM1 ready browsers (IE5+, NS5+, OP4+ etc…)

> When to use if
>   (document.all&&document.getElementById)
>   condition

I can't imagine a sensible use case for such a condition (it's not specific enough).
So obviously the answer is **never**.